# A form of Russell's Paradox

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $S$ be some set and $A=\{x\in S \vert x \notin x \}$. Prove that $A\in S$.

If I assume $A\notin S$ then $A \notin A$ which implies $A\in A$ which is a contradiction. Therefore, $A\in S$.

Is this the correct way to go about proving these statements?

**Edited to add:** The OP has since aknowledged in a comment that the thing to be proven is that $A\notin S$.

Comment: In fact in $\mathsf{ZF}$ one can prove that $\forall x(x\notin x)$, so $A=S$, and $A\color{red}{\notin}S$.

Comment: I'm hesitant to say no, but I didn't follow your argument and I believe the statement you're trying to prove is false: take $S=\emptyset$ for example.

Comment: If $S$ is empty, then $A$ is also empty but $\varnothing\not\in\varnothing$.

Comment: No.  $A \not \in A$ does not imply $A \in A$ because $a \not \in S$.  S is not the universal set so if $A \not \in S$ then .... nothing.

Comment: Let S = {$\emptyset$}.  Then $A = \{\emptyset\} = S$.  But $\{\emptyset\} = S\not \in S$.  Your statement is false.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott are we assuming ZF.  By the very statement of the exercise I assumed we were deliberately not assuming ZF.

Comment: This isn't really a form of russell's paradox as for any sets in ZF yield nonparadoxical trivial results.  Even sets violating ZF need not lead to paradox.  However if we define S to include A as member (antiZF) then we do get a paradox and I believe it would be a form or Russell's paradox.

Comment: @fleablood: I was pointing out that we cannot possibly hope to show that $A\in S$. (And I see that it turns out that the question was indeed stated incorrectly.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott  I'm not disagreeing with you.  With AFZ $x\not \in x$ would true for all $x$ and so $A $ = {all sets in S}.  And by ZFC A not in S.  But I assume to even *talk* about sets containing themselves it is assumed we are regressing to a preZFC state.  Of course then we shouldn't do proofs by contradictions because we can not assume things are well defined in the first place.  Not being able to resolve not P does not mean P can (or must) be resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is false.

Counter example:  $S = \{\emptyset\}$  so $A = \{x \in S|x \not \in x\} = \{\emptyset\}=S$.  But the only element in $S$ is $\emptyset$ and $\{\emptyset\} \ne \emptyset$ and $\{\emptyset\} \not \in S$.

Your argument is faulty in that to have $A \not \in A=\{x\in S|x \not \in x\} \implies A \in A$ we must have $A \in S$ which we do not.

However the opposite $A \not \in S$ can be proven.  If $A \in S$ then either $A \in A$ or $A \not \in A$.   $A \in A \implies A\not \in A \implies A\in A$.  Impossible.  So $A \not \in S$.

Of course, I'm not sure that is complete as I'm not sure we can assume $A$ is always possible.  (If $S$ equals the set of all sets this is exactly Russell's Paradox.)

Comment: Whether $A$ exists depends on your axioms of set theory. Under the axiom of separation (one of the standard axioms of ZF(C)), it always does; under (say) NF (= New Foundations) or positive set theory, it doesn't.

Comment: I was deliberately assuming we were not using the axioms of ZF(C).  If we use ZF(C) then $x \not \in x$ is a redundancy and there's no point in doing this question at all.  If so A must not only exist but be equal to S. However if we are using axioms in which $x \not \in x$ might be a significant statement (i.e. axioms in which $x \in x$ is possible) then such axioms can contain Russell like paradoxes.  Proving $A \in A$ is impossible is no the same as proving $A \not \in A$.  And Proving $A \not \in S$ doesn't mean $A \in S^c$ either.

Comment: yes, sorry - my comment was not meant as criticism of your answer (which is absolutely right), but rather as clarification for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Your argument is false. In particular your claim that since $A \notin A$ it follows that $A \in A$ is false. Let us see why. Recall that $A$ consist of those $x \in S$ such that $x \notin x$ and hence the statement $A \notin A$ only would imply that $A \in A$ if $A$ was in $S$ (which it is not). Are you sure you didn't want to prove that $A \notin S$?

Comment: Ah, I was supposed to prove that $A\notin S$. My apologies.